# Creating a leaderboard from a level completion table

Tags: sql, group-by, leaderboard

I have a table `completion_log` that has `team_id`, `level` and `completion_time`. When each team completes a level, there will be a record inserted with the corresponding level and time values. What is the best SQL query to create a leaderboard from the data - List the teams in descending order of their highest `level` value and if the highest levels are same, sort by the `completion_time` in ascending order?

I tried something like:

```
SELECT team_id, max(level) FROM completion_log GROUP BY team_id ORDER BY max(level)
```

While this almost does the job, this doesn't sort by `completion_time` when the values for `max(level)` for each team are the same. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT team_id, max(level), completion_time FROM completion_log GROUP BY team_id ORDER BY max(level), completion_time
```

You can order by more than one field.

Comment: I get this error in PostgreSQL `ERROR:  column "completion_log.completion_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @guru: Hmmm. Wasn't paying attention. If you want to sort by time, you're going to need to add time to the grouping clause, but that will cause it to add an extra row for every time...